# rowclick event to modify dropdown value in dojo grid

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu, dojo

My requirement is when i click on any row in the enhanced grid, the value in the dropdown menu should change, like when i click on row1,
1st option in the dropdown should be shown, when i click on row2 , 2nd option should show in the dropdown as soon as the user clicks on row2,similarly for other rows...Please find the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/x9kLbqz5/4/.

I can able to get the row information when ever user click on any of the row.Below is the code:

```
    dojo.connect(grid, "onRowClick", function(evt){
     var idx = evt.rowIndex,
    item = this.getItem(idx);
   dojo.byId("results").innerHTML = "You have clicked on " 
                    + this.store.getValue(item, "id");
            });
```

But issue is i could not able to proceed to write the javascript to change the dropdown menu value based on the row user have clicked.
One more requirement is rows should be editable which is achieved using **editable:'true'** while defining the columns.
Please suggest how can i show the dropdown menu list value changed based on the row clicked by the user.Thanks.

--EDIT--

My actual requirement is when i click on any row in the grid, take column1 value and hit the spring controller so that based on that value spring controller returns the dropdown value which i need to show up in the dropdown menu. Please see the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/x9kLbqz5/7/
But issue is when i call javascript function **getDropDownValue(id)**; inside **dojo.connect(grid, "onRowClick", function(evt)** , the rows are no more editable, i want the row to be edited also as well as call the javascript function so that i can make ajax call to spring controller to get dynamic dropdown value and show in the dropdown.

```
        dojo.connect(grid, "onRowClick", function(evt){
         var idx = evt.rowIndex,
        item = this.getItem(idx);
       dojo.byId("results").innerHTML = "You have clicked on " 
                        + this.store.getValue(item, "id");
            var id = this.store.getValue(item, "id");
            alert("item:" + id);
getDropDownValue(id);       
                });

function getDropDownValue(ColumnValue){
    alert("getDropDownValue");
    //ajax call to hit spring controller and get the dropdown value
    var column1 = columnValue;
        var xmlHttp;  
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {
            xmlHttp= new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else if (window.ActiveXObject)
        {
            xmlHttp= new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        var url = <%=request.getContextPath%>+"/getDropDownValue.htm?id="+column1;
        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            handleServerResponse(xmlHttp);
        };
        xmlHttp.open("GET", url, true);
        xmlHttp.send(null);

        function handleServerResponse(xmlHttp)
        {   
           if (xmlHttp.readyState==4 || xmlHttp.readyState=="complete")
           {
              if (xmlHttp.responseText != "null")
              {
           //handle response
              }
           }   
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated the JsFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/x9kLbqz5/5/).
1) SelectedIndex will set the value in dropdown
2) The editable : true is a boolean value and not a string.

Thanks
Srikant

```js
//Set the value in the dropdown
dojo.byId('a').selectedIndex = this.store.getValue(item, "id");
//Editable columns (double click or click +Enter)
var layout = [[
      {'name': 'Column 1', 'field': 'id', 'width': '100px'},
      {'name': 'Column 2', 'field': 'col2', 'width': '100px',editable:true},
      {'name': 'Column 3', 'field': 'col3', 'width': '200px',editable:true},
      {'name': 'Column 4', 'field': 'col4', 'width': '150px',editable:true},
      {'name': 'Last', 'field': 'last', 'width': '150px',editable:true}
    ]];
```

Thanks
Srikant

Comment: Thanks @Srikant Sahu, my actual requirement is when i click on any row in the grid, take column1 value and hit the spring controller so that based on that value spring controller returns the dropdown value which i need to show up in the dropdown menu, to make it simple i modified my question but it seems it doesn't satisfy my requirement , sorry :(.
Can you please suggest how can i call javascript method when i click the row and can access the id in the javascript so that i can make ajax call to spring controller in javascript to get the dropdown value which is retrieved from Database.

Comment: Hi.... I have updated the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/x9kLbqz5/8/ . I have introduced a new function getValuesFromController(id). This actually takes the id and calls a url using dojo/request (ajax)... The then function has a success & error handler which can be used respectively. Please vote the answer if it meets your needs.